# Derivation of alternative form of Chernoff bound

Tags: probability, random-variables, upper-lower-bounds

I have encountered an alternative form for the Chernoff bound for the sum of $n$ coins which I have not been able to derive.
Specifically, let $X_1,...,X_n$ be independent Poisson trials, let $X = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ and let $\mu = \mathbb{E}(X)$. Then
$$
\forall t > 0 .
\mathbb{P}(X \geq \mu + t) \leq \exp\left(-2\frac{t^2}{n}\right)
$$

I am familiar with how to arrive at the more common variant of this Chernoff bound, that is 
$$
\forall \delta > 0. \mathbb{P}(X \geq (1+\delta)\mu) \leq \left(\frac{e^\delta}{(1+\delta)^{(1+\delta)}}\right)^\mu,
$$
but I have not been able to derive the former from it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: parsiad's answer makes use of Hoeffding's inequality, which was introduced in the lecture notes I was reading well after this variant of the bound was presented. So if there is a way to derive this bound without using Hoeffding's inequality/lemma, I would be grateful to see it.

UPDATE:
It is possible to show that the bound on the probability as given by the formula I was looking to derive is actually tighter than the other bound. Hence I don't think it is possible to derive it without Hoeffding's inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n$, let $X_{n}$ be a random variable bounded between $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$.
Let $X\equiv X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}$ and $\mu \equiv \mathbb{E}X$.
Hoeffding's inequality states that 
$$
\mathbb{P}(X \geq \mu + t)\leq\exp\left(-\frac{2t^{2}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(b_{i}-a_{i}\right)^{2}}\right).
$$
In your case, $b_{i}=1$ and $a_{i}=0$ and hence the right hand side above becomes $\exp(-2t^{2}/n)$, as desired.

A proof of Hoeffding's inequality is available on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality#General_case_of_bounded_random_variables).
There is also a good one in the Appendix of Chapter 4 of All of Statistics by Wasserman.

Comment: in a set of lecture notes I found that introduced Hoeffding's Lemma and Hoeffding's inequality in a later lecture. Therefore, whilst this certainly is correct, I would like a proof that does not rely on Hoeffding's inequality. I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: The OP asks about "independent Poisson trials", and they are not bounded...

Comment: Perhaps I am not familiar with the definition of *Poisson trials*. I was under the impression that this referred to a sequence $(X_n)_n$ of independent Bernoulli random variables that do not necessarily have the same success probability. If this is indeed the case, then each one is bounded between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: parsiad is correct @Olivier.
A sequence of Poisson trials is a more general case of a sequence of Bernoulli trials; i.e. it is a sequence of binary-valued random variables with (potentially) different success probabilities. Wikipedia calls such a sequence a 'Poisson Biomial Distribution', I took my phrasing from _Probability and Computation_ by Mitzenmacher and Upfal

Comment: My bad, I did not know this definition, and thought about Poisson random variables !